# Dynamically displaying documents with the Page Viewer web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, document-library, pdf, page-viewer-web-part

At my organization, we have a daily report (pdf) that uploads to SharePoint. This report has its own document library dedicated to holding just this report. the most recent version, as well as historical versions are stored chronologically.

We would like to display the report on a web page. My first thought was to use the page viewer to display the report. The problem is that this will only display the report I selected originally. When a new version of the report is uploaded, the page viewer needs to point to this new document instead.

Is there a way to dynamically have the page viewer display the most recent document in a library, or is there another web part that has this ability?

Comment: Are you saving the daily report file with same name in document library? If you enable the version history on files, save the daily report file with the same name then page viewer web part will always show the latest version of file.

Comment: The documents are uploaded automatically using the incoming email settings. The name is technically different since the system sending the reports add a timestamp to the name (ex. "name - 15 Jan 2021"). The "name" part doesn't change, but the timestamp does.

Answer (score 0):

If the pdf files are stored separately in the document library, I don't think it's possible to dynamically display pdf files in the page viewer web part. You need to choose pdf file to display.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a year ago, but the best way I've found so far is to do a 'Highlighted Content' web part, filter to the desired document library, apply the right filters to only show the 1 file, change the Layout property to 'Carousel', and set 'Show up to this many items at a time' to 1. This will automatically update when a new file matching the criteria is uploaded. The only catch is that the file isn't interactive like it is with a 'File Viewer' web part, but it still displays a preview and the entire window is clickable.